# httpd (apache) centos fail to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: apache, centos7, php-5.4

i'm facing the next error in a centos 7 server

[image: apache issue]

I take a look to similar questions saying that is because SELinux doesn't allow to httpd to write in my /home folder, i've tried changing the owner of the folder without success; try changing the context (chcon) to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` of my /home with the same error; try disabling SELinux and the error persists; and in the file `httpd.conf` change the `User` and `Group` from `apache` to `test` this didn't work either. My server is:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
Release:        7.4.1708
Codename:       Core
```

and

```
Linux localhost 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 25 20:13:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I execute `move_uploaded_file()` from `php -a` as user `test` it works normally, i see that the issue is with the user `apache`

Comment: What are the permissions on /home/test and on /home ?

Comment: Did you try chown -R test:apache /home/test and then giving 750 permission on /home/test?

Comment: hi @jawbonewalk, thanks for the comment I've tried to `chown -R test:apache /home/test` and give the `750` permission to the folder `/home/test` but I see the same error. The permissions to my `/home/test` are **700** and for `/home` **755**

Comment: Did you change /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to point to your folder ?

Comment: yes I add my folder in my httpd.conf, but I finally find a solution and it's about the owner of the folder `/home/test/images/` and the upper folder `/home/test`, for both the owner must be apache and the group too, thanks for the guidance @jawbonewalk

Answer (score 9):

### TLDR:

Do not run `setenforce 0` command, this will disable SELinux! You should not disable SELinux for security reasons.

### The solution:

You should update policy to make SELinux allow read and write on specific directories:

To allow apcahe to read and write.

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/your_writabl_dir
```

For read only directories:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/yourdir
```

---

For example you can make your **public** (document root) directory read only and **only allow write on directories that you allow** you app to write on:

```
# Make all read only
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/myapp

# Only allow write on uploads dir for example
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/myapp/public/uploads
```

Comment: Solution worked for me, but it minimizes the security. If we can have anything, better than that.